# Is there a way to determine the application server name in java

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, jboss, websphere

I work on an application that can be deployed on Tomcat 6.0/ WebSphere 7.0/ WebLogic 10.3.0/JBoss 6.4.

For a certain report I need to get this data (server name) in the application logs.
Is there a way that I can get the application server name at run time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should help -

```
String str1 = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
```

Answer (score 2):

yeah you can do that using Servlet:

```
String str1 = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
```

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).